# MVC 'public virtual Collection...'

Tags: c#, .net, collections, virtual

I am new to MVC. Can any one explain elements at line #8 to 13 in following Auction class:

```
public class Auction
{
    public int lngAuctionId { get; set; }
    public string txtTitle { get; set; }

    public virtual Collection<Bid> Bids { get; private set; }

    public Auction()
    {
        Bids = new Collection<Bid>();
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't specific to MVC. But anyway, the virtual keyword allows any classes that derive from Auction can override the property and use it in any way they want to. The constructor initializes and instantiated the Bids collection. by default, you can only get the property from outside of the class but not set it - you can only set it within the class, like it currently is doing

Comment: You are probably wondering about Entity Framework's lazy loading, which requires properties to be virtual. What is your actual question, what made you ask _this_ question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this class is stored in database by your ORM (like Entity Framework). Making properties virtual allows ORM to override this properties in inherited classes. Why ORM needs that? To allow lazy-loading or entities which are stored in other tables.

How it works. You want to store auctions and bids in database. Relation is simple - auction can have many bids (i.e. bid in database will have foreign key for auction).

When you are loading auctions from database, bids are not loaded if lazy-loading is enabled, which is default (otherwise it can download entire database data for single query). And ORM returns objects which are inherited from auction. Yes, they are still auctions, but of different type:

```
public class DbAuction : Auction
{    
    private DbContext _context;

    public DbAuction(DbContext context)
    {           
        Bids = new Collection<Bid>();
        _context = context;
    }

    public override Collection<Bid> Bids 
    {
        get 
        { 
            // here ORM checks whether this auction has bids loaded
            // and if it hasn't then ORM makes database query
            // and downloads related bids
        } 
        private set { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

So, property marked virtual to allow adding some functionality to getting or setting its value in derived classes. ORM uses this ability to add functionality of additional data loading from database when you trying to get property value.

```
 // this code will return auction of some specific derived type
 // and ORM will load data only from Auctions table
 var auction = context.Auctions.Find(id);
 // and only here due to overridden virtual property
 // ORM will make another call to database and get data from Bids table
 var bids = auction.Bids;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lines 10-13 are the constructor.  so when you do `Auction variablename = new Auction();`, the code at line 12 will be executed.

Line 8 declares a public property named Bids, which uses a generic `Collection<T>`, where T is a Bid.  (Google .NET generics for more info.)  'virtual' means the property can be overridden by child classes.

Answer (score 0):

The class has a collection property that should not be set from outside (therefore the `private set` and the internal one-time initialization in the c'tor). Only the collection values can be manipulated.

But there's no obvious reason why it should be marked as `virtual`.